# Javascript and single-page application: speech recognition not-allowed

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

I want to write a single-page application html webside only with html and javascript that recognize speech to text in Google Chrome v52.

For that I'm using

```
var recognizer = new window.speechRecognition();
```

but always get *not-allowed* at

```
recognizer.onerror
```

I was trying to allow to use the microphone by

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio:true}, onSuccess, onFail);
```

Do you know how to connect the allowance of *navigator* to *recognizer*?
Or do you have a sample that works as single-page application in Google Chrome?

Thank you,
Maik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked - my failure was to use open the local HTML file in Google Chrome: *file:///*

When I deployed it in the web by *https://* everything worked fine :)